# Jenkins declarative pipeline - Trigger Jenkinsfile from another Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I have a Jenkins MultiBranch pipeline project that points to a Jenkinsfile in my git repo. I want it to trigger another Jenkinsfile that is located in the same repo but in different folder.

How can it be done?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it with adding this section to the pipeline:

```
script {
  def util = load("${env.WORKSPACE}/Jenkins/vars/ScriptedPipeline.groovy")
  util.DoSomething()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration of the pipeline you can select the location of the Jenkinsfile relative path

[image: Build Configuration]